# How to create inline lists in materializecss?

Tags: css, materialize

In bootstrap, it is as simple as:

```
<ul class="list-inline">
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

I'm wondering how can it be done [materializecss](http://materializecss.com) without using `<nav>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="categories-container pin-top" style="top: 0px;">
      <ul class="categories db">
        <li class="k"><a href="#all">All</a></li>
        <li><a href="#polygon">Polygon</a></li>
        <li><a href="#bigbang">Big Bang</a></li>
        <li><a href="#sacred">Sacred Geometry</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

here you go -> https://themes.materializecss.com/pages/demo
also you can use class .row

Answer (score 5):

Alternativey, you can just copy the bootstrap style:

```css
.list-inline {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: -5px;
  list-style: none;
}
.list-inline > li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-inline">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```